# Android status bar height in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to find the height of the red square excluding the blue one.

[image]

Comment: I'm curious, why do you want that height?

Comment: I am adding programmatically 3 FrameLayouts in to main layout and I want their sizes to be 0.7*screenHeight, 0.3*screenHeight and another 0.7*screenHeight. I am using the code `Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels` to get the screenHeight. This gets the height including the status bar which makes FrameLayouts a little bit bigger.

Comment: Just posted my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very very much! Helped me a lot.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the height of status bar in your `OnCreate` method, you can use the following:

```
int statusBarHeight = 0, totalHeight = 0, contentHeight = 0;
int resourceId = Resources.GetIdentifier ("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resourceId > 0) {
    statusBarHeight = Resources.GetDimensionPixelSize (resourceId);

    totalHeight = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
    contentHeight = totalHeight - statusBarHeight;
}
```

The variable `contentHeight` now has the value you are looking for.