# Toggleable fullscreen with stable layout using Xamarin.Forms/Xamarin.Droid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.droid

I'm making an app that must be able to toggle between two view modes:

- Fullscreen: the view should show on the entire screen, with no title bar/navigation bar/action bar.
- Semi-fullscreen: the view should still fill the entire screen, but title/navigation/action bars should now appear in front of the view, without resizing the view at all.

To test the behaviour of toggling between these two modes, I have created a simple test project that switches between these two modes every two seconds.

The fullscreen mode is working as intended, but there are two issues with the semi-fullscreen mode, as shown in the images below:

1. The view contents (the Label with five text lines) is pushed down. I want it to remain at the top of the screen, partially hidden behind the system bars.
2. The action bar is shown behind the status bar. I want it to be shown below the status bar.

**What do I need to change in order to get the behaviour I want? (I assume the changes must be made in the ToggleFullscreen function  in Page1.xaml.cs or MainActivity.cs)**

[image]

**My code looks like this:**

App.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ActionBarTest
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var np = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
            np.Title = "ActionBarTest";
            MainPage = np;
        }
    }
}
```

Page1.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="ActionBarTest.Page1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                   VerticalOptions="Start" 
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Label Text="Line one"
                   VerticalOptions="Start" 
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Label Text="Line two"
                   VerticalOptions="Start" 
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Label Text="Line three"
                   VerticalOptions="Start" 
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Label Text="Line four"
                   VerticalOptions="Start" 
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Page1.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ActionBarTest
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    ToggleFullscreen(true);
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    ToggleFullscreen(false);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void ToggleFullscreen(bool isFullscreen){
        Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, !isFullscreen); });
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace ActionBarTest.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "ActionBarTest", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());

            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    ToggleFullscreen(true);
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    ToggleFullscreen(false);
                }
            });
        }

        private void ToggleFullscreen(bool isFullscreen)
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                if (isFullscreen)
                {
                    Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)(
                        SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen
                        | SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation
                        | SystemUiFlags.Immersive
                        | SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky
                        | SystemUiFlags.LowProfile
                        | SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable
                        | SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation
                        | SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen
                    );
                }
                else
                {
                    Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)(
                        SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable
                        | SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation
                        | SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen
                    );
                }
            });
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `Y offset` of `stackLayout` when `isFullScreen = false`. For example, give a name to `stackLayout` in `Xaml` and in the code behiend:

```
private void ToggleFullscreen(bool isFullscreen)
{
    Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {

        if (isFullscreen)
        {
            myStackLayout.TranslationY = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            myStackLayout.TranslationY = -64;
        }

        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, !isFullscreen);

    });
}
```

And in your MainActivity, remove the  `SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation ,SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen` when `isFullScreen = false`:

```
private void ToggleFullscreen(bool isFullscreen)
{
    RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        if (isFullscreen)
        {
            Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)(
                SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen
                | SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation
                | SystemUiFlags.Immersive
                | SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky
                | SystemUiFlags.LowProfile
                | SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable
                | SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation
                | SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen
            );
        }
        else
        {
            Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)(
                SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable
            );
        }
    });
}
```

I have uploaded a sample and you can check: [toggle-model-xamarin.forms](https://github.com/XfHua/toggle-model-xamarin.forms)

> on my phone, the offset had to be -74 -- is there a way of reliably
>   determining it from phone to phone?

You can get the offset by getting the height of `status bar` and `action bar`: use a [dependency service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to get the height first and then set the offset, you can look at this thread about [android-status-bar-height-in-xamarin-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927534/android-status-bar-height-in-xamarin-android).

> The design still flashes while it is repositioned -- is there no way
>   of avoiding a reposition at all?

No idea about the flashes, it seems show the view one by one.

> I didn't mention that the view has elements that are supposed to stay
>   at the bottom edge of the screen, and when using TranslateY, these are
>   moved upwards as well

Under this situation, you can only set the offset to the view you want to change instead of the whole view.

Comment: Thanks! While this works, there are some issues with it. 1) On my phone, the offset had to be -74 -- is there a way of reliably determining it from phone to phone? 2) The design still flashes while it is repositioned -- is there no way of avoiding a reposition at all? 3) Sorry, I didn't mention that the view has elements that are supposed to stay at the bottom edge of the screen, and when using TranslateY, these are moved upwards as well -- is there a way of solving this issue?

Comment: Right, thanks again! The best would certainly be if there was a way to leave the page content as it is "behind" the bars, without any layout changes at all, but if that's not possible, this is a functioning workaround, although a bit hackish. Great to see the MSFT team coming to the rescue!